# Formula for returning a specific date based on input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bit of a puzzle regarding formulas for returning a specific date. At present I have a formula that calculates a date exactly 6 months after the date entered So in column D a date is entered and in column F this formula is set `=IF(D196,EDATE(D196,6),"")`

This gives me a date exactly 6 months later. What I want to do is have the formula produce the date exactly 6 months minus 1 day. I can get the minus 1 day with the formula `=IF(D196,(D196-1),"")`. I just haven't worked out if it is possible to combine the two together somehow. Or am I barking up the wrong tree and need to have a completely different formula?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-subtract-dates-b83768f5-f695-4311-98b1-757345f7e926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throw a -1 at the end of if true formula

```
 =IF(D196,EDATE(D196,6)-1,"")
```

If just

```
  =EDATE(D196,6)-1
```

is used then if there is no value in D196 excel defaults to 1/1/1900

Comment: What is your logical test on cell D196 ?

Comment: if no value is returned then excel will use default 1/1/1900

Comment: Thanks very much for solving this for me! adding the -1 did the trick! Solar Mike - For cell D196 either it is blank or has a date in it. If it is blank then F196 needs to be blank too, which is why there is the IF statement